Not able to see all objects under a folder in Pimcore. Communication failure occuring
In pimcore there are 10 million objects. When i click on the folder to show in grid view it shows error:
Timestamp: Fri Nov 08 2024 10:02:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Status: 0 | communication failure
URL: /admin/object/grid-proxy?classId=1&folderId=41419&xaction=read&_dc=1731040291645
Method: POST
Message:
undefined


I have increased Innodb buffer pool size to 46G
Increased Global wait timeout, read time etc...
Enable slow query log technique and when i click on folder to retrieve info It was showing:

Time: 2024-11-08T04:46:48.085146Z
User@Host: hostname Id: 162
Query_time: 42.447281 Lock_time: 0.000001 Rows_sent: 25 Rows_examined: 35485195
SET timestamp=1731041165;
SELECT object_2.o_id as o_id, object_2.o_type as o_type FROM object_2 WHERE (o_path = '/Assets/folder' OR o_path LIKE '/Assets/folder/%') AND object_2.o_type IN ('object','folder') ORDER BY o_id ASC LIMIT 25;
Time: 2024-11-08T04:47:34.063308Z
User@Host: hostname Id: 162
Query_time: 45.821325 Lock_time: 0.000002 Rows_sent: 1 Rows_examined: 35489690
SET timestamp=1731041208;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM object_2 WHERE (o_path = '/Assets/folder' OR o_path LIKE '/Assets/folder/%') AND object_2.o_type IN ('object','folder');

I have put indexing on o_type, o_path, o_classId on objects .
This is my.cnf file:
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1
max_execution_time = 99999999
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 46G
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_file_per_table = 1
key_buffer_size = 2G
sort_buffer_size = 64M
sort_buffer_size = 64M
tmp_table_size = 64M # Set to 64 MB
max_heap_table_size = 64M # Set to 64 MB
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC
innodb_log_buffer_size = 512M

EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM object_2 WHERE (o_path = '/Assets/folder' OR o_path LIKE '/Assets/folder/%') AND object_2.o_type IN ('object','folder');


mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE objects;



Please include the output if show create table for the underlying table and the output of the explain.

I have append the output above you asked for!

Neither create table, nor the explain seem to match the query in the question. Is object_2 a view?

Please don't use local words like crore here. Not everyone will understand them.

While importing pimcore generates 4 different table related to objects which you can see in objects section of this link:
https://pimcore.com/docs/platform/Pimcore/Development_Tools_and_Details/Database_Model/
when i click on folder to show data in grid view . The above query which i showd in slow query log runs.

Would this get the correct answers, especially since you already have INDEX(o_path, o_type):
    WHERE  o_path LIKE '/Assets/folder%'
      AND  object_2.o_type IN ('object','folder');

Note:  OR is especially not optimizable.  What I did above was to avoid OR while getting [perhaps] the same results.
Since IN acts like OR, this will be even faster for the first query:
( SELECT  object_2.o_id as o_id, object_2.o_type as o_type
    FROM  object_2
    WHERE  o_path = '/Assets/folder%'
      AND  object_2.o_type = 'object'
    ORDER BY  o_id ASC
    LIMIT  25
) UNION ALL
( SELECT  object_2.o_id as o_id, object_2.o_type as o_type
    FROM  object_2
    WHERE  o_path = '/Assets/folder%'
      AND  object_2.o_type = 'folder'
    ORDER BY  o_id ASC
    LIMIT  25
)
ORDER BY o_id ASC
LIMIT 25;

This, together with the new index, cuts back on the number of rows it has to check.  See this if you need the 'next' 25 rows, it is a bit tricky:  Index Cookbook

The query that you have given i cant modify it. Because when i click on folder to fetch all objects in UI these query run by itself from backend to fetch the objects!
